# Duplicate meta-Ball with Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, meta-objects

I set my AN settings on a meta-ball to 20 instances to create something similar to a little brainy blob in motion.

I'd like to duplicate it many times, like an array that includes the animation. Is this possible? The Array is not available, I know that we can convert the animations from nodes to keyframes but I need some help with that.

---

so i had a look yesterday to your answer and .gif explanations. In my case i have this type of node for my brain (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dva0u9MPb_A)

Here is my AN settings : 
[image]

As you understood so well, my goal is to have 2 rows of 10 women front to front. The problem is that from your first screen gif to the 2nd on, the "Object transform Output" node disapears an when i delete mine for the "Object Matrice Output" node, i have no satisfying results. I have another node too, to control my meta-balls. I had multiples try, but it gets complicated for me, even if i know that i'm not far from the solution by your help of course.

Comment: You want those 20 instances to be instances multiple times?

Comment: Yes, like a row of 15 "brains" on the same axe.

Comment: The *Object Transforms Output* node didn't got replaced by the *Matrix Output* node, they are practically the same, the only difference is that it takes a matrix transform, which you can create from the individual transform using the *Compose Matrix* node as in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have an animation of wiggled balls like this:

[image: Node Tree]

If you want to instance this animation 10 times, compose matrices from their transforms and replicate them based on the transformations of the second-level instances using the *Replicate Matrices* node. You should, of course, increase the amount of instances from $n$ to to $10\cdot n$ as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Much thanks Omar for your answer! I'll test it tomorrow  :))